# accounts.locations.media not working anymore?

Tags: google-my-business-api

I'm trying to get a list of photos from a location in GMB but it throws me the Google 404 with the error message and "That's all we know" as if this feature didn't exist.
I noticed that Google is refactoring its GMB API to a version called v1 instead of v4.9 which was the old one.
As a result, to use the whole features you have to work with 2 APIs, the v1 and the non-yet deprecated functions in v4.9, ok fair enough.

So I try to fetch a list of pictures associated to my location from the v4 API, that's only a GET request according to this [doc](https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest/v4/accounts.locations.media/list) but with no success.

Do someone know the right way to work with media files related to GMB locations?

FYI: I work with the official google API client in PHP and had to create a class that handles Media queries like described in the [doc](https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest/v4/accounts.locations.media)

Comment: First sanity check: account, location and media actually exist and are visible through the UI?

Comment: Yes all is visible through the GMB UI. There is actually one account with many locations and each of those have user and customer photos.

Comment: Could you try it via the OAuth playground? https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/basic-setup#make-simple-http-request

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the 404 error means you are using a wrong project ID. Have a look at  [this link](https://support.google.com/business/thread/51122278/how-to-solve-404-not-found-errors-for-any-request-to-https-mybusiness-googleapis-com-v4?hl=en#:%7E:text=%3E%20You%20may%20be%20experiencing%20the,project%20with%20GMB%20Api%20enabled.).
shortly it says:

> You may be experiencing the 404 Method not found error that typically happens when you are using a different Project ID from the
> one we whitelisted for your company to access the Google My Business
> API.
>
> The clientId/secret used to get the access_token are created under the
> project with GMB Api enabled.